# D3 range returning half of graphHeight instead of 0 when all domain input values are 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When domain values are different the code works fine.

[image]

But when all the domain values are 0, the bar height becomes 140 which is half the graphHeight instead of 0.

[image]

Here is my code sample:

```
const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .rangeRound([0, graphWidth])
            .padding(0.4);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .rangeRound([graphHeight, 0]);

const draw = (data) => {

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.type;}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.number;})]);

rects.enter()
     .append('rect')
     .on('mouseover', onMouseOver)
     .on('mouseout', onMouseOut)
     .merge(rects)
     .attr('fill', '#30aaed')
     .attr('x', d => x(d.type))
     .attr('y', d => y(d.number))
     .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
     .attr('height', d => graphHeight - y(d.number))
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This issue occured in d3 v5. So, I solved it using d3 v4.